# Dynamic Array - Finding Capacity

Tags: c++, stdvector, dynamic-arrays

I have been looking through the std::vectors source code and looking at how it's capacity (vector.capacity()) function works, i'm not quite understanding how i would implement it into my Dynamic array source code. I would not just be returning the current container size would i. e.g dynarray.size().
,Thanks

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator> 
#pragma once
template<typename T>
class DynamicArrayIter
{
public:
    DynamicArrayIter(T* data) : newData(data) { }
    //DynamicArrayIter(const DynamicArrayIter& o);                   // Copy constructor
    //DynamicArrayIter& operator=(const DynamicArrayIter& o);        // Assignment operator
    DynamicArrayIter operator++() { DynamicArrayIter i = *this;newData++; return i;}
    DynamicArrayIter operator++(int junk) {newData++;return *this; }
    T&   operator*() {return *newData; }                   
    bool operator==(const DynamicArrayIter& rhs) {return newData == rhs.newData; }
    bool operator!=(const DynamicArrayIter& rhs) { return newData != rhs.newData;}
    DynamicArrayIter<T> operator+(int _i)
    {
        DynamicArrayIter<T> iter = *this;
        for (int i = 0; i < _i; ++i)
        {
            if (iter.newData) //If there's something to move onto...
                ++iter;
            else
                break;
        }
        return iter; //Return regardless of whether its valid...
    }
private:
    T* newData;
};

template<typename T>
class DynamicArray
{
public:
    DynamicArray<T> operator=(const DynamicArray<T>&);//Dynamic Array equals Dynamic Array
    DynamicArray();//Constructor
    ~DynamicArray();//Destructor
    void push_back(const T&);//Push back a new element into the DynArray
    void pop_back();//Pop an element off the back of the DynArray
    void print();//Prints out what is in the container
    bool empty();//Empty the DynArray container
    void reserve(int);//Reserver a size of which the Dynarray can reach, once it reachers the limit it will increase etc.
    void resize(int);//resize the Dynrray container data will be carried into the new size either cutting off eccess data or reserving space for more.
    void swap(DynamicArray<T>);//Swap the contents in the Dynarray with another Dynarray containers.
    void assign(size_t,T);//Assign new content to the Dynarray, replacing the current elements and changing its size accordingly
    void assign(DynamicArrayIter<T>, DynamicArrayIter<T>);//Assign new content to the Dynarray, replacing the current elements and changing its size accordingly
    void insert(DynamicArrayIter<T>,T);//Insert a element at a certain positon elements will be moved and adjusted accordingly
    void erase(DynamicArrayIter<T>);//Erase an element at a certain postion
    void erase(DynamicArrayIter<T>,DynamicArrayIter<T>);//Erase an element at a certain postion
    T& at(int );// Element postion at index
    T& front();//elements t postion
    T& back();//elements back position
    T& operator[] (int);//subscript location access
    size_t capacity();//capacity of the container
    size_t max_size();//max size of the vontainer
    DynamicArrayIter<T> begin();//Begin on the container/DynArray - Iterator uses this to grab the begin of the Dynarray
    DynamicArrayIter<T> end();//End on the container/DynArray - Iterator uses this to grab the End of the Dynarray
    void clear();//Clear the whole container
    int size();//Size of the current container returns sizeofarray
private:
    T* myArray;//Where data is stored
    int sizeofarray = 0;//size of the current container
};

template<typename T>
inline DynamicArray<T> DynamicArray<T>::operator=(const DynamicArray<T>&newDynArray)
{
    myArray = new T[newDynArray.size()];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < newDynArray.size(); i++)//will make the current array the size of the new one
    {
        myArray[i] = newDynArray.myArray[i];//Current Dynarray = the pass in Dynarray - Steps through changign each element
    }
    return newDynArray;//return the passed data
}

template<typename T>
inline DynamicArray<T>::DynamicArray()
{
    myArray = new T[sizeofarray];//Creating a new Dynarray of size
}

template<typename T>
inline DynamicArray<T>::~DynamicArray()
{
    delete[] myArray;//deleting the Dynarray
}

template<typename T>
inline void DynamicArray<T>::push_back(const T& pusheddata)
{
        T *temp = myArray;//Creating a temp array with the value of the current Dynarray
        myArray = new T[++sizeofarray];//Dynarray = new Dynarray of current size + 1 // Size is being incremented from this
        myArray[sizeofarray - 1] = pusheddata;//Pushing the element onto the back of the Array
        for (int i = 0; i < sizeofarray - 1; ++i)//It is sizearray - 1 as we dont the temp does not have the data we just pushed onto the back
        {
            myArray[i] = temp[i];//going through a loop putting the data from the temp we created back into the DynArray.
        }

        delete[] temp;//delete the temp

}

template<typename T>
inline void DynamicArray<T>::pop_back()
{
    T *temp = myArray;//Creating a temp array with the value of the current Dynarray
    myArray = new T[sizeofarray--];//Dynarray = new Dynarray of current size - 1 // Size is being decreased from this
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeofarray; ++i)
    {
        myArray[i] = temp[i];//Dynarray equals the temp values
    }
    delete[] temp;//Delete the temp

}

template<typename T>
inline void DynamicArray<T>::print()
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeofarray; i++)
    {
        std::cout << myArray[i] << std::endl;//Just looping through and printing the element until it hits size.
    }

}

template<typename T>
inline bool DynamicArray<T>::empty()
{
    if (size() == 0)
    {
        return true;//return true if size is 0
    }
    return false;//return flase if size >=1
}

template<typename T>
inline void DynamicArray<T>::reserve(int r_size)
{
    sizeofarray = r_size;//size = the reserve size

}

template<typename T>
inline void DynamicArray<T>::resize(int newsize)
{
    T *temp = myArray;//Creating a temp with the current Dynarray inside of it
    myArray = new T[newsize];//Dynarray = a new Dynarray of size (newsize)
    for (int i = 0; i < newsize; ++i) 
    {
        myArray[i] = temp[i];//Setting the Dynarrays elements to the temps
    }
    for (int i = sizeofarray; i < newsize; i++)
    {
        myArray[i] = NULL;//Set the elements outside the size allowed to NULL
    }
    sizeofarray = newsize;//Size = new size
    delete[] temp;//delete the temp
}

template<typename T>
inline void DynamicArray<T>::swap(DynamicArray<T> newSwap)
{
    clear();//clear the current Dynarray
    for (size_t i = 0; i < newSwap.sizeofarray; i++)
    {
        myArray[i] = newSwap.myArray[i];//Newly cleared Dynarray elements = passed in swapped data
        sizeofarray++;//increment the size
    }
}

template<typename T>
inline void DynamicArray<T>::assign(size_t n, T val)
{
    clear();//Clear the Dynarray
    myArray = new T[n];//Dynarray = new Dynarray of size_t n
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)//for i < size_t n
    {
        myArray[i] = val;//Dynarray  = val passed through
        sizeofarray++;//increment the size of the Dynarray
    }
}

template<typename T>
inline void DynamicArray<T>::assign(DynamicArrayIter<T> first, DynamicArrayIter<T> last)
{
    int n = 0;//temp size holder
    for (DynamicArrayIter<T> iter = first; iter != last; ++iter) {
        n++;//increment the temp size holder
    }
    clear();//clear the Dynarray
    myArray = new T[n];//Make a new Dynarray and its size is the temp size holders
    for (DynamicArrayIter<T> newiter = first; newiter != last; ++newiter) {
        myArray[sizeofarray] = *newiter;//Iterate through and set each element to the value passed in
        sizeofarray++;//incremenet the size
    }
}

template<typename T>
inline void DynamicArray<T>::insert(DynamicArrayIter<T> position, T val)
{
    int sizeofthis = 0;//temp size holder for iter
    int j = 0;//Index position // increments when position is meet
    for (DynamicArrayIter<int> iter = begin(); iter != position; ++iter){
        ++sizeofthis;//increase the temp size holder fo riter
    }
    T *temp = myArray;//Create a new temp Dynarray
    sizeofarray += 1;//temp size hodler + 1
    myArray = new T[sizeofarray];//Dynarray = new Dynarray of temp size holder for iter
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeofarray; i++)
    {
        if (i == sizeofthis)//if the for loops i = tempsize holders
        {
            myArray[sizeofthis] = val;//Dynarray element = val being passed in
            j++;//Index pos ++
        }
        myArray[i + j] = temp[i];//Dynarray = Temps values // Will change when inserted pos is reached // dynamically chagne size
    }
    delete[] temp;//delete temp
}

template<typename T>
inline void DynamicArray<T>::erase(DynamicArrayIter<T> position)
{
    int sizeofthis = 0;//temp size holder for iter
    int j = 0;//index pos//increments wehn pos is met
    for (DynamicArrayIter<int> iter = begin(); iter != position; ++iter) {
        ++sizeofthis;//increment the temp size holder
    }
    T *temp = myArray;//temp = current Dynarray
    sizeofarray -= 1;//size decreased by 1
    myArray = new T[sizeofarray];//new Dynarray of the new size
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeofarray; i++)
    {
        if (i == sizeofthis)//if the loops i reaches the temp size holders value
        {
            myArray[sizeofthis] = myArray[sizeofthis + 1];//Dynarray at sizeoftihs = Dynarrays next element
            j++;//index pos ++
        }
        myArray[i] = temp[i + j];//Dynarray = the temp[idexpos will be greater > 0 if i == sizeofthis]

    }
    delete[] temp;//delete the temp

}

template<typename T>
inline void DynamicArray<T>::erase(DynamicArrayIter<T> first, DynamicArrayIter<T> last)
{
    int sizeofthis = 0;
    for (DynamicArrayIter<int> iter = first; iter != last; ++iter) {
        ++sizeofthis;
    }
    T *temp = myArray;
    sizeofarray = sizeofarray - sizeofthis - 1;
    myArray = new T[sizeofarray];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeofarray; i++)
    {
        if (i < sizeofthis)
        {
            myArray[sizeofthis - 1 + i] =NULL;
        }
        myArray[i] = temp[i];

    }
    delete[] temp;

}

template<typename T>
inline T & DynamicArray<T>::at(int place)
{
    return myArray[place];//return the element at place
}

template<typename T>
inline T & DynamicArray<T>::front()
{
    return myArray[0];//return the first element in the array
}

template<typename T>
inline T & DynamicArray<T>::back()
{
    return myArray[sizeofarray];//return the last element in the array
}

template<typename T>
inline T & DynamicArray<T>::operator[](int place)
{
    return myArray[place];//return  the element at place using subscript operator instead of dynarray.at()
}

template<typename T>
inline size_t DynamicArray<T>::capacity()
{
    return back() - front();//
}

template<typename T>
inline size_t DynamicArray<T>::max_size()
{
    return std::numeric_limits<T>::max();
}

template<typename T>
inline DynamicArrayIter<T> DynamicArray<T>::begin()
{
    return DynamicArrayIter<T>(myArray);
}

template<typename T>
inline DynamicArrayIter<T> DynamicArray<T>::end()
{
    return DynamicArrayIter<T>(myArray + sizeofarray - 1);
}


template<typename T>
inline void DynamicArray<T>::clear()
{
    sizeofarray = 0;
    myArray = new T[sizeofarray];
    myArray[0] = NULL;
}

template<typename T>
inline int DynamicArray<T>::size()
{
    return sizeofarray;
}
```

Comment: ... what's your question? We can't see your "Dynamic array source code", nor can we know how to add capacity functionality to it.

Comment: `size()` reports the number of items that have been added to the container. `capacity()` reports how many items the container has allocated memory for before it has to allocate more memory. For example, if you set the capacity to 10, the container will not have to allocate more memory until 10 items have already been added and an 11th item is being added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`size()` returns the number of elements that are held by the container while `capacity` is how many elements it can hold before more space must be allocated. So capacity can be greater than the size of the vector.

In your implementation, you have to create one more member `capacity` that will store the actual size of allocated array whereas `size` will hold the number of elements the container is holding.

Comment: Thanks, Will do that.

Comment: Agreed with 0x0001 - also, when increasing the capacity, the std::vector<T> class doesn't increase it's capacity by 1 every time an element is added. It increases by preset amounts - so when it is constructed, for example, it will allocate 8 elements for a capacity of 8 and a size of zero. Once the size==capacity, it will then increase it's size by another 8 elements, so its size will be a size of 9 with a capacity of 16. 

The main reason it doesn't constantly resize is to reduce overhead.